# PHP Order by ASC not working on decimal type

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

Have a quick question regarding ORDER. I have a list of scores I am displaying in a high scores table using php. I need the lowest decimal number to display in 1st place, however when I try to use the ASC command, no results display. But if I use DESC the results do display, but in the opposite order to what I need (lowest decimal displays last).

Here is the "working" code that displays the scores, but in the wrong order.

```
$query = mysql_query("select reflex,playerID from users_stats order by reflex DESC limit 10")or die(mysql_error());

$ranking = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         if ($row[reflex] <= 0) break;
            $ranking = $ranking + 1;  
            $rankingdisplay = doRankPosition($ranking);  

            print "<tr><td><b>$rankingdisplay</b></td><td>$row[playerID]</td><td>$row[reflex]</td></tr>";
        if ($ranking >= 10) break;       
    }
```

Here is the code that displays nothing (no results are returned).

```
$query = mysql_query("select reflex,playerID from users_stats order by reflex ASC limit 10")or die(mysql_error());

$ranking = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         if ($row[reflex] <= 0) break;
            $ranking = $ranking + 1;  
            $rankingdisplay = doRankPosition($ranking);  

            print "<tr><td><b>$rankingdisplay</b></td><td>$row[playerID]</td><td>$row[reflex]</td></tr>";
        if ($ranking >= 10) break;       
    }
```

I have also tried this (default);

```
$query = mysql_query("select reflex,playerID from users_stats limit 10")or die(mysql_error());

$ranking = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         if ($row[reflex] <= 0) break;
            $ranking = $ranking + 1;  
            $rankingdisplay = doRankPosition($ranking);  

            print "<tr><td><b>$rankingdisplay</b></td><td>$row[playerID]</td><td>$row[reflex]</td></tr>";
        if ($ranking >= 10) break;       
    }
```

And again, no results display....

The reflex score is being stored in a MySQL database using decimal(4,3) default None. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried to google it, but can't seem to find anything specific to what I need. I assume it is something to do with decimal??

Thanks in advance.

*EDITED - I do appreciate any answers/advice, however I am very new to php and still desperately trying to learn :/

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated, use php's pdo or mysqli classes to access the database, by using mysql_* you are open to sql-injection attacks...

Comment: You don't have to explicitly use `ASC`, as it's the default. But where's your attempt? I'm only seeing the alleged _"working"_ case. Also, does the column have any `null` values?

Comment: `"no results display"` - Can you be more specific?  Show the non-working code and explain some debugging information.  Regardless of the end result on the web page, are any records returned from the query at all?  What happens if you run the query against the database manually?  Are there any errors from the database or in the PHP logs?

Comment: What I said was you could ommit _the `ASC` keyword, not the whole `ORDER BY`_! (= your third example)

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have 0 in column "reflex" and line

```
 if ($row[reflex] <= 0) break;
```

made exit from cycle